# How to aggregate partial weeks in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate, partial

There are lots of great ways to aggregate timestamp based data into weeks. But I've got a real tough one, aggregating a partial week.  I've googled this for a few days, racked my brain and found some really hard & ugly ways to solve it with programing for loop. There must be a elegant solution using tidyverse.

Lets say I've got logs of bird sightings in a timestamp format. Two columns:  timestamp, birdname

It is easy to aggregate a count by week like

```
birds_per_week<- data %>%  group_by(week = cut(timestamp, "week", start.on.monday = TRUE)) %>%   summarise(n())
```

But I have a real tough one, I want to know the **partial week** count.  Let say today is 10am on Monday and I want to know all the weekly counts of between 10am Mondays thru noon on Wednesdays.  That is a 2 day 2 hour window.  In my problem, the endpoint is always noon Wednesday, but the starting point varies.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(timestamp = structure(c(1540505400, 1539802080, 1538778660, 1538417640, 1538691660, 
1538790780, 1538705100, 1539614520, 1539893280, 1539455520, 1540343580, 
1540178220, 1538628960, 1539533280, 1539572700, 1538823480, 1538967480, 
1538468400, 1540425600, 1539809880), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""))
```

First break out day and hour parts:

```
df1$day <- weekdays(df1$timestamp)
df1$hour <- hour(df1$timestamp)
```

Then filter to our three days, then exclude the beginning and ending hours of Monday/Wednesday:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% filter(day %in% c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")) %>% 
  filter(!(day == "Monday" & hour < 10)) %>% 
  filter(!(day == "Wednesday" & hour > 12))

df1$week <- week(df1$timestamp)
```

Then use `week` as your group:

```
df1 %>% group_by(week) %>% summarize(count = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   week count
  <int> <int>
1    40     2
2    42     1
3    43     1
```

Comment: Well, the first part of this works.  But if I have to do a comparison from Saturday 2am thru Wednesday at noon, the week count will chop it off. So no good there. I'm trying to incorporate Jon Spring's week split solution.

Comment: Keeping it simple, you can just adjust week like `df1$week <- epiweek(df1$timestamp+days(1))` to make the week start on Saturday instead of Sunday, and you won't lose your Saturday days.

Comment: OK, this works, but I don't understand _why_.   The documentation on 'epiweek' is thin. Can you explain what the epiweek does here?  BTW, I like this solution. --edit-- I shouldn't put this in production unless I understand how it works.

Comment: I used `epiweek` here because it always runs Sunday through Saturday. `lubridate::week` returns the number of "seven day periods since January 1st plus one", and I think it's possible that creates issues between years. The main key here is knowing what the start and end day of your week are. It doesn't really matter what day it is, as long as you compensate your adjustment accordingly. In this case, I know `epiweek` runs Sunday-Saturday, so if I add 1 day to `timestamp`, that shifts your week so Saturday is part of it (your week would be Saturday - Friday).

Answer (score 0):

It seems one approach would be to note the "next Wednesday noon" for each row and then count those.

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr)

times_to_test <- data.frame(times = seq.POSIXt(from = ymd_h(2018102400),
                            to   = ymd_h(2018110123), by = "hour"))

times_to_test %>%
  # For checking, helps to see which days are wednesdays
  mutate(weekday = wday(times, label = T)) %>%
  # Wednesday noon is 3.5 days (84 hours) into the week
  mutate(next_Wed_noon = floor_date(times + dhours(84), "1 week") + 
           dhours(84)) %>%
  count(next_Wed_noon)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  next_Wed_noon           n
  <dttm>              <int>
1 2018-10-24 12:00:00    12
2 2018-10-31 12:00:00   168
3 2018-11-07 12:00:00    36
```

Comment: I see this breaks it from noon-wednesday to next noon-wednessday  but how does it achieve my partial week aggregate count?

Comment: This counts how many observations occur in the week prior to each Wednesday noon. If the endpoint of your partial weeks is always noon Wednesdays, I thought that would capture any partial week, whether it starts Tuesday, Monday, or even the prior Wednesday evening.

Comment: Yes, but it doen't have any code that lets it know when my partial week starts. ie. if I start on Friday at 2am or on Tuesday at 4pm.  This will simply count all instances.  I think I can combine it with Mako212's answer below. We'll see.

Comment: Would it work to first filter out any dates prior to your week? It might be helpful if you could include an example of input and output.

Comment: Well, hang on, I'm not sure this does do a 7 day week cut.  If i do a quick week to week difftime i should get 7 days, but I get -3.5 days.  'difftime (floor_date(now() + dhours(84), "1 week"), floor_date(now() + dhours(84), "1 week")+ 
            dhours(84), "days")'